# How to shuffle MNIST data loaded using Keras?

Tags: keras, mnist

I am using MNIST dataset from keras -

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

Before loading the data, how can I shuffle this dataset?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to do this with `keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()`.

You have different options:

1. Download the dataset yourself and load it directly from your files. Then shuffle and split it
2. Use `tensorflow_datasets`. Example:
   `import tensorflow_dataset as tfds`

   `(df_train,df_test)=tfds.load('minst',split=['train','test'],shuffle_files=True,  as_supervised=True)`
3. Build a dataset from your x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test. Then shuffel and split it again.

Comment: Some thing wrote wrong, it should be `import tensorflow_datasets as tfds`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as tensorflow suggests,

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds 
(ds_train, ds_test), ds_info = tfds.load(
    'mnist',
    split=['train', 'test'],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)
```

I am not sure but you can use this and convert into numpy as follows:

```
    import numpy as np
    ds_test_np = np.array(list(ds_test.as_numpy_iterator()))
    ds_train_np = np.array(list(ds_train.as_numpy_iterator()))
```